# How to delete data with linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

This code is giving me this error:

> The object cannot be deleted because
>   it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager

```
using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities())
            {

                var q = (from t in context.tag
                        where t.tag_id == tag
                        select new
                        {
                            t
                        }).FirstOrDefault();



                if (q != null)
                {
                    context.DeleteObject(q);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous object with `new {t}` that just happens to contain a property called t of type Tag, which is not registered in the ObjectContext. You don't have to write `select new {t}`, just `select t` will return your Tag object.

Answer (score 0):

Try just selecting `t` and not making an anonymous object with t as a property.